# fluid openlayers - responsive design

Tags: css, responsive-design, openlayers

I am trying to have my openlayers map fit the size of the browser and also resize every time the browser resizes. So I can have responsive design.

My structure of code is like so

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='OpenLayers.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>


var map;
var options = {   
  controls: [],
  maxResolution: "auto",
  projection: "EPSG:900913",
  units: 'm'
}

function init(){
 map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_element', options);
 //set layers, styles for vectors layers, set and activate click events etc.
}

</script>


<body onload='init();'>

<div id='map_element' style=" width:800px; height:400px ; z-index:1; position: relative;text-align:center;"> </div>
```

According to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31409/openlayers-redrawing-map-after-container-resize) I tried using

```
//if browser loads 
//this is inside init() because = body.onload > init > resize map
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_element', options);
map.updateSize();

//if browser resized
    window.onresize = function()
    {map.updateSize();}
```

but does not work

Also, if I set `style=" width:100%;` in the `map_element` `div` the map disappears from the page.

What is happening? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example:
http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/fullScreen.html

This is responsive and CSS does most of the work via width and height set to 100%.

Comment: Thanks, but that is for fullscreen. I did try to edit my code, according to the example's code and nothing. Map still disappears form the page

Comment: EDIT  Works only if I set `height:100%` in the `div` that contains the map's `div`. But if I set a height, then some elements overflow, since I have a dynamic content. So , fixes the map, "destroys" the container...Think I'm gonna set no height for the container and just use media queries for the map